Identifying primary key in basic ERD diagram
I can't figure out the primary key for the Office entity described below. The diagram  is for a national honor's society. I included info about the Chapter entity, since I think I have to use it to create a composite primary key for the Office table:

There are several offices in each chapter.
Each office can belong to only one chapter.
An office also contains such positions as President or Treasurer.
The office has a Title, Job Description, and Election Date.
Most offices are managed by one of the chapter members, however there are times when an office will be unfilled.

The chapter entity:

There are many chapters in the ABC honor society.
Each chapter is identified by its Name, and
has a sponsoring School, Charter and Charter Date.

What's the pk here for the office table? is it office title? could i make a composite pk by using the office title and the chapter name?

If you were involved with this organization & you or anyone wanted to refer to a particular office or chapter, what word(s) or phrase(s) would be necessary & sufficient & why so? (Rhetorical.) PS But the reference for the design method you are following says how to use the method, which is it & what does it say that is relevant & how are you 1st stuck? PS How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? PS [ask] [Help]

The primary key uniquely identifies an entity among all the others.
Looking at the office attributes, titles do not appear unique enough.  You could for example have a "president" in each chapter.  You could alternatively consider the combination of chapter name and title, e.g. "president" of the "New York" chapter.  But this natural composite key would have constraints.  For example, you could not have two "vice-president" offices in the same chapter.  Also you would need to make sure that the chapter name is really unique, and also does always use the same spelling (including upper/lower case).  Moreover, what if a chapter gets renamed ?
Alternatively,  you may consider using a surrogate key. It's not part of the domain attributes identified for the entity,  but is an additional attribute that ensures unicity of the identity independently of any domain attribute.
